# How to store variations for html elements in BeautifulSoup calls through many sites?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am scraping site data, the data itself is very simple and obviously displayed on each page.  But since each site is different, the actual HTML structure varies.

eg

*site 1*

```
site = 'https://www.site1.com/items'

page = requests.get(site)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

#items are stored in divs with class "item-container"
item_soup = soup.find_all(class_ = 'item-container')

items_to_store = []
for item in item_soup:
    #within the div, the "true" name is stored as the alt-text for the item's image
    items_to_store.append(item.img['alt'])
```

*site 2*

```
site = 'https://www.site2.com/section/items'

page = requests.get(site)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

#items are stored in spans with class "item-title"
item_soup = soup.find_all(class_ = "item-title")


items_to_store = []
for item in item_soup:
    #within the span, the "true" name is stored as text
    items_to_store.append(item.text)
```

These two snippets are identical except for

- url
- the tag details for finding the items
- the way the item name is extracted

Rather than just copy/paste the code for each site, and replacing the relevant bits, I'd prefer to write a function.  Ideally this function would take in the site, reference a dictionary where I store the relevant tag details, and pull the relevant data to re-scrape.

Is there a way to fill the parameters in `soup.find_all()` and `items_to_store.append()` dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than `.find_all()` you can use CSS selectors. Then you can define one function that takes URL and return CSS selector string and function that takes tag as parameter and extracts the information from the tag.

For example:

```
txt_site1 = '''
    <div class="item-container"><img alt="this is the information from site 1" /></div>
'''

txt_site2 = '''
    <span class="item-title">this is the information from site 2</span>
'''


def sites(site):
    if 'www.site1.com' in site:
        return 'div.item-container img[alt]', lambda tag: tag['alt']
    elif 'www.site2.com' in site:
        return 'span.item-title', lambda tag: tag.text


def universal_scraper(soup, url):
    css_selector, item_getter = sites(url)

    item_soup = soup.select(css_selector)

    for item in item_soup:
        yield item_getter(item)


all_items = []
soup = BeautifulSoup(txt_site1, 'html.parser')  # load site1
all_items.extend(universal_scraper(soup, 'https://www.site1.com/items'))
soup = BeautifulSoup(txt_site2, 'html.parser')  # load site2
all_items.extend(universal_scraper(soup, 'https://www.site2.com/section/items'))

print(all_items)
```

Prints:

```
['this is the information from site 1', 'this is the information from site 2']
```

---

If you want solution with `.find_all()`, you can try this:

```
def sites(site):
    if 'www.site1.com' in site:
        return lambda soup: soup.find_all(class_ = 'item-container'), lambda tag: tag.img['alt']
    elif 'www.site2.com' in site:
        return lambda soup: soup.find_all(class_ = "item-title"), lambda tag: tag.text


def universal_scraper(soup, url):
    item_finder, item_getter = sites(url)

    item_soup = item_finder(soup)

    for item in item_soup:
        yield item_getter(item)

# the rest is the same...
```